# linear-gradient a un hr

Tags: css, html5

¿Alguno sabe cómo ponerle un `linear-gradient` al `<hr>`?

la clase es `skills-hr` y no noto las transparencias, simplemente está blanco como si no se aplicara el estilo.
A parte tengo que revisar *Bootstrap* y unas cositas, pero el punto principal es que no me aplica el estilo al `<hr>`, es un detalle, pero ya lo quiero sacar.

Decidí no agregar más cosas de HTML ya que no vienen al caso y considero que con esto es suficiente para resolver la pregunta, de no ser así pedir el resto.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1, h2, h3,p, span{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
/*HEADER*/
.header{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.header-content h1, h3 {
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #000000e8;
}
.header-content h3{
  width: 50%;
}
/*SERVICIOS*/
  .servicios{
      text-align: center;
  }

.row-serv{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
.row h3{
  color: #000;
}
.row p{
  text-align: start;
}
.row-left{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.row-right{  
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.dis{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.admin{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
/*SKILLS*/
.skills-container{
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(#36bed9,#29bad7);
  
}
.col-xs-12{
  text-align: center;
}
.skills-hr{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #FFFFFF, transparent);
}
img{
  width: 10rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-container">
        <div class="skills">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h2>SKILLS</h2>
                    <hr class="skills-hr"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/html.svg" alt="HTML5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/css.svg" alt="CSS3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/javascript.png" alt="Javascript">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/bootstrap.svg" alt="Bootstrap">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/jquery.svg" alt="jQuery">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/git.svg" alt="Control de versionado">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/npm.svg" alt="NPM">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/react.svg" alt="React.js">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/firebase.svg" alt="firebase">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <img src="img/bd.png" alt="Bases de datos relacional">
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: deja un poco más de contexto, el html y la hoja de estilos para ver si no hay algo pisandolo, porque en teoría eso esta correcto

Comment: ahora lo edito, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes ocultar los estilos por defecto que tiene la etiqueta `<hr>`, para ello puede jugar con la propiedad `border: 0;`, seteas el ancho `width: 80%;`, el alto `height: .1rem;` y finalmente le asignas el color con la propiedad `background-image: linear-gradient(to right,transparent,#f5f9fa,transparent);`.

Ajústalo a tu necesidad para obtener el resultado que deseas.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #36bed9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.linea {
  border: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: .1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,transparent,#f5f9fa,transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>skillset</h3>
  <hr class="linea">
</div>
```

Comment: Buenísimo! Muchos gracias!!!